# how to position a scroll_to_top button

Tags: html, css

in the example below how to keep `gotop` inside `story` - i.e. bottom right of the middle div
and keep its `show/hide` functionality
the three divs - `top, story and footer` - are not of predictive width and height
I tried various position and margin params - without success

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
let x = $(this).scrollTop();
if(x > 25){$('.gotop').show();}
else{$('.gotop').hide()}
});

$('.gotop').on('click', function(){
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
.container{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
background:silver;
text-align:center;
}
.top{padding:25px; background:gold;}
.story{
position:relative;
padding:25px;
min-height:100vh;
}
.footer{padding:25px; background:gold;}

.gotop{
display:none;
position:fixed;
z-index:99;
right:14px;
bottom:0;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<div class='top'>TOP</div>
<div class='story'><br><br><br><br>STORY<br><br><br>
<div class='gotop'>gotop</div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry. What's the issue?

Comment: @Pytth - `gotop` is outside of `story` - far bottom right of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sticky position:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  let x = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (x > 25) {
    $('.gotop').show();
  } else {
    $('.gotop').hide()
  }
});

$('.gotop').on('click', function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
}

.top {
  padding: 25px;
  background: gold;
}

.story {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  min-height: 150vh;
  /* I need flexbox to push the button to bottom*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.footer {
  padding: 25px;
  background: gold;
}

.gotop {
  display: none;
  position: sticky;
  margin-top:auto; /* push to bottom */
  text-align:right; /* right align */
  z-index: 99;
  right: 14px;
  bottom: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='top'>TOP</div>
  <div class='story'><br><br><br><br>STORY<br><br><br>
    <div class='gotop'>gotop</div>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following implementation, I have taken some liberty to change minor css , replace jquery with js by introducing **Intersection Observer** which will only make the `gotop` element visible when our `footer` starts getting visible. Ofcourse you can use both jquery and js simultaneously but since I don't have experience with former, I used js only.

The benefit is that it's not dependent on any hardcoded values to control `gotop` visibility.

```js
let footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
let gotop = document.querySelector('.gotop');

let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries)=>{
entries.forEach(entry=>{
if(entry.isIntersecting){
 gotop.style.opacity = '1';
 gotop.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
}
else{
 gotop.style.opacity = '0';
 gotop.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
})
})


observer.observe(footer);

gotop.addEventListener('click',()=>window.scrollTo({top:true}));
```

```css
.container{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
background:silver;
text-align:center;
}
.top{padding:25px; background:gold;}
.story{
position:relative;
padding:25px;
min-height:100vh;
}
.footer{padding:25px; background:gold;}

.gotop{
opacity:0;
pointer-events:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
right:14px;
bottom:0;
cursor:pointer;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<div class='top'>TOP</div>
<div class='story'><br><br><br><br>STORY<br><br><br>
<div class='gotop'>gotop</div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change `position:fixed;` to `position:absolute;` for your `.gotop` div. Since it is positioned inside a `position: relative` div then it will be inside of it.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
let x = $(this).scrollTop();
if(x > 25){$('.gotop').show();}
else{$('.gotop').hide()}
});

$('.gotop').on('click', function(){
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
.container{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
background:silver;
text-align:center;
}
.top{padding:25px; background:gold;}
.story{
position:relative;
padding:25px;
min-height:100vh;
}
.footer{padding:25px; background:gold;}

.gotop{
display:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
right:14px;
bottom:0;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<div class='top'>TOP</div>
<div class='story'><br><br><br><br>STORY<br><br><br>
<div class='gotop'>gotop</div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls read the post carefully. The second row

Comment: pls check the answer carefully. You asked to position the "goto" inside of your "STORY" div at the bottom right... That's what I did.

Comment: And it keeps the show/hide functionality. You just don't see it because it happens before the text appears on screen. You need to fix your jquery as well. 

If you set the .goto bottom to be 50% you will see what I mean